# batch opening a webpage and screenshot it after 10 seconds

Tags: batch-file, firefox, screenshot

I'm trying to create a batch where I open firefox, wait for 10 seconds so the web page is loaded and finally i take a full screenshot.

i tried "firefox www.google" and I know there is an option "screenshot --full page" but i cant make it work altogether.

My main target is clicking in a batch and getting a screenshot of several web pages. And if its possible, wait 10 seconds after opening the web page so it's loaded properly.

thanks

This is what i tried without even trying the 10 seconds delay, but it doesn't work :

```
firefox www.google.uk & firefox --screenshot
```

Comment: I don't want to seem overly negative, but if you don't know the command or method how are we supposed to help you with your script?

Comment: the command is firefox , and we can use an OS as for example Raspbian based on Debian from a Raspberry Pi 2 B. That line would be inside a script

Comment: I can guarantee that on no computer that the command `firefox` will create a full page screenshot. Additionally, if you take a look at the `[batch-file]` tag description, it is for `MS-DOS`, `OS/2` or `Windows`, not any flavour of `Unix`. Perhaps you need to completely overhaul your question, tags and title if you want to attract an appropriate audience.

Answer (score 1):

What about this batch script ?

```bat
@echo off
Title Take a screenshot with snippingtool by Hackoo 2018
start /min "" firefox.exe "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50029056/batch-opening-a-webpage-and-screenshot-it-after-10-seconds"
Timeout /T 10 /nobreak>nul
Start /Wait snippingtool /clip
Start /Max mspaint
```